# Delphi XE2 - Unable to connect to Gmail smtp server via SSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, gmail, openssl, delphi-xe2

Using Delphi XE2, Indy 10 that ships with it and OpenSSL dll's version 1.0.1c.

We are in the final stages of converting our Delphi 6 project to Delphi XE2.

We have solved every show stopper so far but I am running into one trying to connect to Gmail smtp server.

Our Delphi 6 app works fine using SSL v2.3 and SSL v3 and Indy 9 components connecting to port 465 per Google's own documentation. [Google Support](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287)

Our Delphi XE2 app does not connect at all. The call to connect goes into the ether and nothing happens for some 7 minutes until I get bored waiting for the thing to timeout and kill it off. I actually traced the program execution all the way to the IdWinsock2 funcion here:

```
function Stub_select(nfds: Integer; readfds, writefds, exceptfds: PFDSet; timeout: PTimeVal): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  @select := FixupStub(hWinSockDll, 'select'); {Do not Localize}
  Result := select(nfds, readfds, writefds, exceptfds, timeout);//<-this line never returns and timeout is always nil
end;
```

I need to maintain the old SSL connectivity for existing users' configurations.

New users will be able to connect using TLS (to port 587) and that DOES work!?!?

I am at a loss as to why the non-TLS SSL options do not work and do not report any error and do not time out but just go off to Never-Never Land. Please help!

TJ

Here is the code:

```
  SMTPClient.Host := trim(EditSMTPServer.Text);
  SMTPClient.Port := EditSMTPServerPort.AsInteger;//<- value from custom edit box
  SMTPClient.Username := trim(EditSMTPLogon.Text);
  SMTPClient.Password := trim(EditSMTPPassword.Text);
  SMTPClient.AuthType := satDefault;

  if CheckBoxUseSSL.Checked then begin
    SMTPClient.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.ReadTimeout := 30000;//30 second timeout which does not appear to work
    case ComboBoxSSLMode.ItemIndex of
      0 : IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv2;
      1 : IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      2 : IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
      3 : begin
        IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLsv1;
        SMTPClient.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
      end;
    end;//case
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2.SSLOptions.Method := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2.PassThrough := False;
  end
  else begin
    SMTPClient.IOHandler := nil;
  end;

  try
    SMTPClient.Connect;
    if SMTPClient.Connected then begin
      if SMTPClient.Authenticate then begin
      ... do some work ...
      end;
    end;
  except
    on e:Exception do begin
      showmessage(e.message);
    end;
  end;
```

EDIT:

As usual, after I post a question I have stumbled across a workaround.

If I set the UsetTLS property to utUseImplicitTLS for all NON-SSL transactions and set it to utUseExplicitTLS for TLS transactions my connections appear to work in a timely manner.

Hopefully this helps someone out.

updated code:

```
if CheckBoxUseSSL.Checked then begin
  SMTPClient.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
  SMTPClient.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  case ComboBoxSSLMode.ItemIndex of
    0 : IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv2;
    1 : IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    2 : IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    3 : begin
      IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLsv1;
      SMTPClient.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    end;
  end;//case
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2.SSLOptions.Method := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2.PassThrough := False;
end
else begin
  SMTPClient.UseTLS := utNoTLSSupport;//reset TLS support flag
  SMTPClient.IOHandler := nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you discovered is what you are supposed to be doing.  SSL and TLS have different semantics, so you have to set `UseTLS` accordingly.

For SSL on port 465, the server expects your client to initiate an SSL handshake immediately upon connecting, before the server then sends an encrypted Greeting.  `UseTLS=utUseImplicitTLS` does that, but `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS` does not.  When `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS`, `TIdSMTP` will expect the server to send an unencrypted Greeting immediately, which would explain the hang in `select()` - the server is not sending any data!

For TLS on port 587, the server is expecting the client to connect initially unencrypted and then send an explicit `STARTTLS` command when it is ready to initiate encryption.  `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS` does that, but `UseTLS=utUseImplicitTLS` does not.

Comment: _Hmm, `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS` does that, but `UseTLS=utUseExplicitTLS` does not_, one of those is wrong

Comment: One of the `UseTLS=` in your final sentence needs to use `utUseImplicitTLS` (**Implicit**) - both of them mention **Explicit**, and one of them is obviously wrong. I'm suspecting it's the second one that should be `utUseImplicitTLS`, but not sure enough to edit your answer to make the correction. :-)

Comment: Remy, thanks for the info! Your explanation makes sense and I get what's going on now.

Comment: Is there an Indy10 TLS/SSL+SMTP demo app somewhere with all this shown?